# Logic and number theory books

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, logic, book-recommendation

I've recently decided to start preparing for uni, so I figured I need to learn logic and some number theory. I picked up Burton's Elementary Number Theory and wasn't quite comfortable with
it, seemed very dry throwing out expressions which I couldn't understand since I'm in still in high school.

Could you recommend me any books on subject which are written in a more approachable manner to a highschooler? I need basics: arithmetic, primes, divisibility, Diophantine, some Fermat maybe.

I also plan on taking some logic. Looking through Tarski's book a little it seemed broad, with not enough emphasis on mathematics. I need some recommendations on that one too. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: The book I suggest in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/641239/55235) answer will catapult your mathematical maturity two years into the future.

Comment: For an introduction to logic with an emphasis on mathematical proofs, may I humbly suggest the tutorial that comes with proof-checking freeware. For a list of features, testimonials, a demo video and PC-based download, visit my website at http://www.dcproof.com. Also, an introductory book on calculus may be a better choice than number theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peruse these:

- William Leveque - Elementary Number Theory
- Underwood Dudley - Elementary Number Theory
- Oystein Ore - Invitation to Number Theory
- Mathew Crawford, - Introduction to Number Theory, Art of Problem Solving
- Joseph H. Silverman, A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory ($$$)

You can also find free notes online and the first three are Dover books with great prices.

For gentle logic books, see [Logic and set theory textbook for high school](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641236/logic-and-set-theory-textbook-for-high-school?lq=1).

Also learn to do proofs (cannot be stressed enough), see [how to be good at proving?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/190981/how-to-be-good-at-proving).

Comment: found Underwood Dudley's on Gutenberg,seems pretty decent,definitely what was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

A great second book : "Computability and Logic" George S. Boolos & Richard C. Jeffrey