# Recommend a concise book on mathematical logic

Tags: logic, book-recommendation

I am looking for a concise book which explains the symbolic logic required for mathematical proofs, such as the use of quantifiers and logical connectives. Which book should I use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the logic symbols used in _standard_ mathematics, or the subject of _mathematical logic_ itself? If all you need is how to use quantifiers in proofs it wouldn't be hard to explain that.

Comment: The logic symbols used in standard mathematics. For example,  in a recent proof I used the fact that $(x \in A) \vee (\forall X \in \mathscr{C}) x \in X \equiv (\forall X \in \mathscr{C}) [(x \in A) \vee (x \in X)]$. This step seemed valid since $(\forall X \in \mathscr{C})$ only acts on the second disjunct, but I didn't fully understand why the operation was valid. I am looking for a book that explains things like this, so I know that they are valid when they are needed in proofs.

Comment: My I humbly suggest the tutorial that comes with my proof-checking freeware. For features, testimonials, introductory video and PC-based download, visit my website at http://www.dcproof.com

Comment: "Symbolic Logic" by Graeme Forbes is very good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the first two chapters of Daniel J. Velleman's widely available and widely praised *How to Prove It* (CUP)? That covers the connectives in Ch. 1 and the use of quantifiers in Ch. 2, with lots of explanations and illustrations. (The whole book is well worth reading if you are a relative beginner at mathematics.)

Comment: [I back up](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641236/logic-and-set-theory-textbook-for-high-school/641239#641239) this recommendation.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is exactly what I'm looking for.