# Where can I find a derivation of high school mathematics based on the simplest axioms, principles and definitions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Basically something that starts with the substitution principles, definition of an equation, of subtraction and division, axiom of opposites, your usual commutative, associative, distributive axioms, and covers all the way up to the end of high school trigonometry.

Dolciani's two volume "Algebra: Structure and Method" was good but I need another similar work.

Serge Lang's "Basic Mathematics" wasn't good enough.

Reading the first few chapter of abstract algebra books wasn't that helpful as they were too broad in scope.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: The book Calculus by Spivak takes the axioms for the real numbers as a starting point. It does also give a development of the trig functions.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Related: [Books for middle-school-level algebra that covers some set theory and "axioms of algebra"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2519875/13130)

Comment: Analysis I and II by Tao.

Comment: @Dr. Momo: *Analysis I and II by Tao.* --- Since the OP wrote "Dolciani's two volume "Algebra: Structure and Method" was good but I need another similar work", I seriously doubt Tao's books would be suitable. [contents for Dolciani Volume 1](https://isbn.nu/toc/9780395461402) AND [contents for Dolciani Volume 2](https://isbn.nu/toc/9780395771181)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I don't know... Tao develops the usual number systems (naturals, integers, rationals, and reals) from scratch and gives a definite definition of trigonometric functions, etc. There is an appendix about the equality relation and logic. That seems to be what the OP is asking for?

Comment: @Dr. Momo: I suppose we need to know whether the OP wants a book for someone still learning (or recently learned) school algebra and trigonometry vs. a book for someone at the advanced undergraduate / beginning graduate university level for a mathematics major. If the latter, then Tao will work, but then so would several hundred other books for a similar mathematical maturity level.

Comment: One possibility, but it stops well before trigonometry, is **The Anatomy of Mathematics** by Kershner/Wilcox ([1950 1st edition](https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.509287) -- also [here](https://archive.org/details/anatomyofmathema0000kers); [1974 2nd edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=FlkgAQAAIAAJ)). Another possibility, this one being primarily exponential and trigonometric functions, is [**The Non-Algebraic Elementary Functions. A Rigorous Approach**](https://www.google.com/search?q=Yandl+%22The+Non-Algebraic+Elementary+Functions%22&filter=0) by André Louis Yandl (1964).

Answer (score 2):

You might like some of Hung-Hsi Wu's books such as 'Pre-Algebra', 'Algebra and Geometry', and 'Pre-calculus, Calculus and Beyond', available from the AMS. The books are aimed at teachers of mathematics, but everything is done rigorously from scratch. Wu goes into more detail than I have seen in any other books covering the content of school mathematics.

To get a flavour of his work, there is an old draft of his Pre-Algebra book available on his website [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ewu/Pre-Algebra.pdf).